# views not displayed using viewsphp module

Tags: drupal-7

hai
i created a view using custom fields only (using views php module). the problem is that the view is not displayed. but if i add node id as an extra field the view is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the view still needs to know what data to show, and depending on how you set up your view, you may have set it to use exposed filters. Turn off exposed filters. This should disable the required input field.